# How is this implemented in selling app without app store opening

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

Please check screenshots below. As you can see developers added some code to sell ( for free )
other application without opening app store. 
How did they implement this ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK these are links that are generated from iAd Workbench. You need to create a campaign for a particular app in App Store.

https://iadworkbench.apple.com/app/#campaign

[image]

From [Apple Docs][2]

> **Campaign Creation Workflow**
>
> Campaign creation consists of following steps:
>
> *Step 1*: Create Campaign - (Method: CreateCampaign)
>
> Specify App or Product, placement type, bid type
>
> *Step 2*: Create Line - (Method: CreateLine)
>
> Specify Auto or Manual targeting. With manual targeting, granular
>   targeting can be specified: e.g., Country, Creative and Destination
>   Type, Delivery dates, Budget and Bid values
>
> *Step 3*: CreateAd - (Methods: CreateAd, UploadAd, VerifyAd, SaveAd)
>
> Choose Template or Upload creative option For Template, pick template
>   name and color. Also, specify the Title, description, Call To Action.
>   See template details in “Appendix 2.” For upload, upload all the
>   assets and verify the Ad. Creative assets should conform to the specs
>   in
>   https://developer.apple.com/iad/creative-specifications/iad-creative-specifications.pdf)
>   For destination, choose iTunes or Website and fill in destination
>   details For detailed information on Ad creation, refer to “Appendix
>   1.”
>
> *Step 4*: Assign Ad to Line (Method: AssociateAdToLine)
>
> *Step 5*: Submit the campaign - (Method: SubmitCampaign)
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zzduy.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxcpq.png   [2]:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/General/Reference/iAdWorkbench_Reference/Document/iAdWorkbenchAPIGuide_Ch1.html

Comment: so the only way to achieve what i want is create iAd Banner and show it inside app ?

Comment: @YegorRazumovsky Yes for sure.